# Match one column of data frame to another, pull in other columns, combine into large dataset

Tags: r, match, zipcode

I've got a list of Store IDs and their Zipcodes in a 2 column numeric vector (in R). I'm using the "Zipcode" package (https://cran.rproject.org/web/packages/zipcode/zipcode.pdf) and have access to the longitude/latitude coordinates for these zipcodes. The zipcode package has a data frame with every zip code, city,state, and longitude and latitude for all the zipcodes (as a large dataframe).

I'm looking to get the longitude and latitude coordinates for my Zipcodes, and add them as columns 3 and 4 (i.e. Store ID, Zip Code, Longtitude, Latitude)

Any thoughts? 
Thank you!

EDIT: I've tried the merge function (i.e.) total<-merged(CleanData,zipcode, by=zip) and I'm getting an error because they must have the same number of columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column name passed as the `by` argument has to be enclosed within quotes. You don't need the `by` argument in merge in this example, **if** zipcode is the only common column in the two dataframes.

> Example datasets:

```
#cleanData
d1<-tibble::tribble(~z,~id,131,1,114,2,155,5)

#zipcode
d2<-
tibble::tribble(~z,~x,~y,131,2,5,166,2,6,162,6,5,177,7,1,114,2,1,155,5,9)

result <- merge(d1,d2)
```

gives

```
       z id x y
    1 114  2 2 1
    2 131  1 2 5
    3 155  5 5 9
```

You can remove any unnecessary columns from the result dataframe by simply using `dplyr::select()`. Suppose you don't need column **y** (which may be a state name, for example)

```
result <- dplyr::select(result, z, id, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using this: [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

essentially I used the Left Outer function because I wanted to keep all of the zipcodes in my store database. I believe the answer above would eliminate zipcodes not found in the second list of zipcodes.